# Asigning access rights to folders in linux CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, rights

I'm trying to assign rights to folders for groups in linux CentOS.
can someone tell me the syntax used to do that

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

chmod -R 3771 /directory/path

chgrp -R Directie /directory/path

setfacl -d -m g::rwx /directory/path